# how to Inject {% include snippetname.liquid %} in cart liquid automatically during app installation?

Tags: php, shopify, code-snippets, shopify-app

I am facing a problem in my Shopify app submission. The problem is the reviewer person told me to insert code automatically by app itself instead of manual inserting code.

Actually I am working on APP in which I need to insert snippet on my cart page just above the submit button. I am doing this manually and it is working fine. But I now,I need to do this automatically as this is the requirement of "Shopify APP store listing". I got email from APP Reviewer that it must be done automatically by app itself.

My APP is working fine there is no other issue in it. Please Help me to solve this issue.

About APP: My APP is build using PHP. In snippet it is just adding a checkbox on cart page before moving to checkout process.

Comment: Check out script tag feature of Shopify

Comment: Lol seriously... I hate apps that modify the theme code this way, and Shopify forces you to do this... The only way achieve this is to use the `Asset API` and modify the cart template or section, the problem is that you must know if the button is in the template /  section / snippet... so you are limiting your App to work only in specific cases, if the client is using custom theme you are a little screwed since you won't know where to look (the button can be everywhere). So you MUST have a manual option as well. (@HymnZ the Scripts API is only for JS, you can't add liquid code with it)

Comment: @drip .. No clue what the op's app is about or even what the so-called snippet contains. As a shop owner, it'd be great if the themes are not touched because many apps leave junk when uninstalled. So the only sure way to ensure the theme remains clean is by using js injection or an app-proxy which here is overkill.

Comment: @HymnZ yep I totally agree. Just wanted to throw that out in case OP got confused that he can add the snippet with the Script Tag API.

Comment: Yeah this is the main issue,, some themes use Ajax cart, some use sections cart-template.liquid and some only use cart.liquid. 
is there any way to find out  where is the exact cart page in the theme?

Answer (score 0):

As per all the comments, your App is considered bad if you inject Liquid manually or if you use Asset API calls to modify the theme. So instead, embrace JS and the Script Tag. With that you can detect if you are on the cart page, and if you are, add DOM elements to accomplish your goals, in conjunction with your App. There is no overkill really, use what you're provided with, and use it well.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your comment but how we can add DOM element if we don;t have any idea about button used on cart page. the button may be simple button or input button.  what if the cart page is custom means the classes, id's are not same as the default classes?

Comment: That is your true problem. I am sure you can figure it out. detecting a button is one of the easier problems we've mastered with computers !

Comment: Yes, @David Lazar the problem is fixed and it is running fine.